# Size of child class with diamond inheritance structure seems strange

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, sizeof

I have 4 classes A, B, C, D.
B and C inherit A, and D inherit B and C.

If A, B, C, D doesn't have any member variable, `sizeof(D)` returns 1(which is expected).
But when B has one integer as member variable, `sizeof(D)` suddenly changes to 8.

Since `sizeof(int)` is 4, shouldn't `sizeof(D)` return 4 as well?

```cpp
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
    int data;
};

class C : public A
{
};

class D : public B, public C
{
};

int main()
{
    sizeof(A); // 1
    sizeof(B); // 4
    sizeof(C); // 1
    sizeof(D); // 8?
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the standard doesn't actually place much restriction regarding such issues.

Comment: What happens if your use `char` or `short` instead of `int`? My guess is that maybe the compiler pads the entire thing to 8 bytes.

Comment: Alignment requirement, it ensures that the *data* member is still aligned when you create an array of D objects.  That can't work the compiler reserves 5 bytes of storage, it takes the next multiple of 4.  Technically this could be optimized since the storage for C is never accessed, but that's one bridge too far.

Comment: @Thomas I changed int to char, and sizeof(D) returned 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 `A` subobjects in `D`, and they must have distinct representations. The *lower bound* on `sizeof(D)` is therefore `1 + sizeof(int)`.

The implementation you used chose to size `D` such that `(sizeof(D) % alignof(D)) == 0`.

Your implementation is non-conforming in the entirely empty case, as it has put two distinct `A`s in the same storage.